# Getting HTML DOM element and setting it to a value of a input tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

There is an element on my page with the id `last_name`. I would like to get its value and pass it along to my `input` tag.

I am essentially trying to do something like this (doesn't work).

```
<input type="hidden" name="lastName" value=document.getElementById("last_name").value>
```

Is there anyway to do this?

This is not only on  load.

Essentially, I have a bunch of textboxes grouped together in a form.

Then I have another form with a button. When the user hits the button, I want my input tags' values be the current values entered in the textboxes.

EDIT: Thanks all! Got it work. I essentially had to remove the "value" attribute of the input tags and then add an "onclick" attribute to my button and then call those javascript codes you guys provided me.

Comment: Code is missing :)

Comment: But with jQuery you can do `$('input').val( $('#lastname').text() );`

Comment: This is ran as soon as the DOM loads?

Answer (score 1):

for only loading page:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <!-- link here your JQuery library -->
        <script>
           $(function(){
              $('#lastName').val($('#last_name').val());
           });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body> 
        <input type="text" id="last_name" value="123"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="lastName" value="">
    </body>

</html>
```

for button click:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
        <!-- link here your JQuery library -->

        <script>
           $(function(){
              $('#btn-save').on('click', function() {  
                  $('#lastName').val($('#last_name').val());
                  // other work
                  return false;
              }
           });
        </script>
    </head>

    <body> 
        <input type="text" id="last_name" value="123"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="lastName" value="">
        <button id="btn-save">Save</button>
    </body>

</html>
```

without jQuery use:

```
        <script>
            window.onload = function(){
               var src = getElementById('last_name');
               var dst = getElementById('lastName');
               dst.value = stc.value;
           }
        </script>
```

Comment: Would this only work the first time I load the page?

Comment: Would this work only the first time I load the page? I essentially have a bunch of textboxs, and a "save" button. When the user hits the button, I want the input tags to have the current value of these textboxs, and then I will send this info to my backend

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var lastName = document.getElementById("last_name");
var input = document.getElementById("yourInputId");
input.value = lastName.value;
```

Comment: It would be best to try to explain to the OP what you're doing and why instead of handing over some code that they may not know how to implement.

Comment: @buschschwick in most cases I would agree with you but this is a fairly straightforward problem with a straightforward solution where the code has enough to explain what's going on and adding additional comments would be superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code
HTML

```
<input type="hidden" name="lastName" id='hidLastName' />
```

and javascript code:

```
var input = document.getElementById("hidLastName")
   input.value =  document.getElementById("last_name").value
```

Answer (score 0):

You should move the logic to a .js file or inside a  `<script></script>` element. Preferrably the former. Try something like this:

Put an id to the receiving input:

```
<input type="hidden" id="lastName" name="lastName">
```

And this to your .js file

```
window.onload = function(){
    var lastNameInput = document.getElementById('lastName');
    var sourceInput = document.getElementById('last_name');
    lastNameInput.value = sourceInput.value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:
Java Script

```
<script>
    function setInput() {
        document.getElementById("lastname").value = document.getElementById("last_name").value;
    }

</script>
```

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="last_name"  onblur="setInput()"/>
<input type="hidden" id="lastname" />
```